# Create symbolic links to block devices by partition table UUID

Tags: linux, udev, block-device

Within `/dev/disk`, there are the folders `by-id`, `by-label`, `by-partlabel`, `by-partuuid`, `by-path`, and `by-uuid`. Is there a way to make what software responsible for this create a directory called `by-ptuuid` and populate that directory with symbolic links whose names are the partition table's UUID on the parent block device that they point to?

Comment: Please [edit] and explain how it would be different than `by-partuuid`. Do you mean [partition type GUIDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#Partition_type_GUIDs)? or what? Please make sure there is no [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310) here. Why do you need this?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I said `partition table's UUID`. That should be enough. Just look at the specification for GPT.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with a custom udev rule, for example:

```
ENV{ID_PART_TABLE_UUID}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-ptuuid/$env{ID_PART_TABLE_UUID}"
```

You could put it in a file like `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-by-ptuuid.rules`. And for each partition table with PTUUID (partition table uuid), it should symlink back to the block device accordingly.

However, this lacks any additional checks. So this can include strange results like partitions / logical volumes with VM or ISO images on them, even though nested partition tables are usually not considered by the kernel.

Comment: Is there a way to add additional checks?